# How do you maintain the state of a checkbox-toggled div after page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that appears when a checkbox is checked, and hides when unchecked. If the form has errors, the page reloads and the div appears hidden even if the checkbox was checked before submission. I can add a call to the onLoad event, but is there a cleaner way to ensure that, after page reload, the div is rendered based on the status of the checkbox?

Css:

```
#maintenance-window { display: none; }
```

jQuery:

```
$("#check-hasMaintenance").click(function() {
    $(this).is(":checked") ? $('#maintenance-window').show("fast") : $('#maintenance-window').hide("fast")
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="check-hasMaintenance">
<div id="maintenance-window">
    Stuff
</div>
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I would do.

Comment: Agree, I'm afraid you are stuck with JavaScript and onLoad for that, if you don't want to do some kind of server-side validation and add an extra class to the div when the page is rendered, that hides the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Ensure div is shown based on check box when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Modified for readability - inline if is fine.
     if($("#check-hasMaintenance").is(":checked"))
         $('#maintenance-window').show("fast")
     else
         $('#maintenance-window').hide("fast");
});
```

Simplified hide/show code:

```
$("#check-hasMaintenance").click(function() {
    $('#maintenance-window').toggle('fast');
});
```

**Option 2**

A short-hand version like this should work as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#maintenance-window').toggle($("#check-hasMaintenance").is(":checked"));
});

$("#check-hasMaintenance").click(function() {
    $('#maintenance-window').toggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: in your first example, I would have to change `this` to the object id, otherwise the document will not know what I mean by `this`, right?

Comment: @Mohamad, refresh the page, I fixed that copy + paste error ages ago :)

Comment: thanks. I can confirm that the short hand version works. I have the JS in a separate file that's loaded in the body. I have everything wrapped in a `$(function() {});` -- is this necessary if I have no inline JS?