# How do you maintain the state of a select-menu-toggled div after page reload?

Tags: jquery

I have two spans that appear or hide when their respective option is selected from a select-menu. By default, both spans are set to `display: none` in CSS. I would like to maintain the visibility of any currently visible span after the page reloads (in case there was a validation error, for example).

I did this with a checkbox and it was easy, but I can't figure it out with a select-menu.

```
    // Toggles the div based on selected option
$(function() {
    $('#maintenanceIntervalId').change(function() {
        var value = $('#maintenanceIntervalId option:selected').val()

        switch(value) {
            case "2": {
                $("#weekly-maintenance-on").show();
                $("#monthly-maintenance-on").hide();
                break;
            }
            case "3": {
                $("#monthly-maintenance-on").show();
                $("#weekly-maintenance-on").hide();
                break;
            }
            case "1": {
                $("#weekly-maintenance-on").hide();
                $("#monthly-maintenance-on").hide();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The above works as expected. But in order to get the currently visible span to stay visible after page reload, I moved the switch statement into its own function `toggleMaintenanceDiv()` and added the following line:

`toggleMaintenanceDiv($('#maintenanceIntervalId option:selected'))`

This does not work, however.

HTML:

```
<select id="maintenanceIntervalId">
    <option value="1">Day</option>
    <option value="2">Week</option>
    <option value="3">Month</option>
</select>

<span id="weekly-maintenance-on">Stuff one</span>
<span id="monthly-maintenance-on">Stuff two</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is reloaded each time with page loading, all variables or states of javascript will be lost after reloading. I think you can store the visible span IDs in cookie and when the page loads each time, it checks the cookie first and sets corresponding spans visible.

Comment: I'm not sure a cookie is necessary in this situation. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406336/how-do-you-maintain-the-state-of-a-checkbox-toggled-div-after-page-reload