# maintain the state of a radio-toggled div after page reload

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button, toggle, reload

In my form there are some radio buttons - when the radio is selected - the div appears, when another one is selected - the div hides. After submitting a form if there are some errors, page reloads and the div should still show (if the radio was selected). The solution below works only for checkboxes - how to make it work for radio's?
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/8406409/1137417 
Here is my code:

```
    $(function(){

    $('#Q07_03, #Q07_07, #Q08_03').hide();

    // checkboxes
    $('#Q07_03').toggle($('#Q07_02').is(':checked'));
    $('#Q07_02').click(function() {
    $('#Q07_03').toggle(); });

    $('#Q07_07').toggle($('#Q07_06').is(':checked'));
    $('#Q07_06').click(function() {
    $('#Q07_07').toggle(); });

    // here code for radio ?
    // #Q08_03 is the div to be displayed;
    // #Q08_02 is the one that should be selected
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ajax to submit the form? You will not face these kind of issues. Well to answer your question you can try this.

```
//I don't know how many radio buttons are there on the page and what there names are
//you can accordingly change the radio button selector to check if it is checked or not

$(document).ready(function() {
     if($("input:radio:first").is(":checked"))
         $('divToShowHide').show()
     else
         $('divToShowHide').hide()
});
```

Comment: I've updated my post so that you can see the code. Your solution doesn't seem to work... I don't k now ajax that much but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: There must be some easy solution...?