# remember the state of .attr after page reload

Tags: jquery, state, attr, checked

There are some checkboxes in my form: by checking one, you disable another. The below code works very well. The problem is that when the user gets an error after submitting (when the page reloads) the disabled checkbox is enabled again. But I want it to preserve its disabled state.

```
<label for="Q09_01">
  <input class="Q09" name="Q09[]" id="Q09_01"  type="checkbox" />
aaa</label>
<label for="Q09_02">
  <input class="Q09" name="Q09[]" id="Q09_02"  type="checkbox" value="Q09_02" />
bbb</label>
<label for="Q09_03">
  <input class="Q09" name="Q09[]" id="Q09_03"  type="checkbox" value="Q09_03" />
ccc </label>
<label for="Q09_04">
  <input class="Q09" name="Q09[]" id="Q09_04"  type="checkbox" value="Q09_04" />
ddd </label>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

$('#Q09_01').click(function() {
$('#Q09_03').attr('disabled', this.checked);
});
$('#Q09_03').click(function() {
$('#Q09_01').attr('disabled', this.checked);
});

})
```

Apart from this specific problem, I've had another similar issue with radio buttons ([maintain the state of a radio-toggled div after page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9004958/1137417)) and maintaining show/hide/toggle state on page reload. Is there some jQuery function that would remember ALL of those states after the page reloads? Do you think this http://www.jasonsebring.com/dumbFormState  could help in what I want to achieve? I'm new to jquery and I'll appreciate any help or hints or examples of good practices.

Comment: did you manage to fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this. You can either handle this in your server-side script by checking across your POST input and matching it up. Essentially, check if the variable is defined (or has value) and if not, mark the box disabled. In your case, actually, you're checking the actual submitted value, so this would actually just follow your jQuery logic. Some primitive PHP for example:

```
$disable_Q09_01 = $_POST['Q09'] == "Q09_03"

<input class="Q09" name="Q09[]" id="Q09_01"  type="checkbox" 
  <? if ($disable_Q09_01) echo "disabled"; ?>
 />
```

And forgive me, it's been a while since PHP, I just figured it'd be more common than giving Rails code.

The other method would be to create a cookie before the form is submitted. W3 documents all of this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). Essentially set a cookie of `"disable_Q09_01=true"`, then read or clear it based on the application. I believe this method to be less desirable as the user may have cookies turned off, but this will work (ish) no matter what Server Side Script you're using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know php that much so if there was another option, I'd prefer to avoid putting php scripts to my page this time. I'm sure there must be a way to do it in jQuery but I can't figure out how.

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using local or session storage to store the states of your inputs?
you could then load the input state on page load if the session or local storage exist.

This can be done with javascript/jquery

it would ivolve no server code or cookies

try this for more info

http://www.beakkon.com/tutorial/html5/web-storage

@atmd83

Comment: What about browsers support? I can't find any information on this.

Comment: In jQuery, maybe  just some simple condition could solve my issue? Something like **' if #Q09_01 is checked, disable #Q09_03'** ?

Comment: You can use ie behavour as a fall back to support ie6 onwards

Answer (score 0):

You can't use jQuery to remember the page state. When the page is refreshed, the HTML will be re-sent, defaulting it back to the original state. If you're willing to use a server-side language, such as PHP, then this doesn't have to be the case. But as you said in a comment, you don't want to use PHP.

Therefore, you have two options:

1. Cookies
2. HTML5 web storage

#2 will not be supported by all browsers, so I'd recommend going with #1. Essentially, when a user checks a box, a cookie is created/updated. Then upon page reload, after the document is ready (`$(document).ready(..)`), you'd use JavaScript to read the cookie and make the necessary changes to the DOM (i.e. checking the correct boxes).

[Here's a commonly used jQuery cookie plugin.](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

If you have trouble with creating/updating/reading cookies, you should post a new question specifically about that.